# PHP Include failing when it shouldnt

Tags: php, include

I have an include 'functions.php' which holds things such as connection details and various custom functions.

It works perfectly with every page but i just created a new page in a new dir, adjusted the include link accordingly, and the page is correctly included.

BUT, when using any of the functions from the include it breaks the page.

```
 include '../../../functions.php'
```

Is this an acceptable way of linking to a a functions include? Is this why its broken?
I normally use this method of linking and never had an issue, but today its not worked and has really rather puzzled me.

It works perfectly until i attempt to call any of the functions within the functions include.

example of a simple function that breaks the page

```
 function functionsTest() {
        echo "functions.php Included Correctly! ";
    }
```

The functions page works perfectly across the rest of the site, and has only broken on this newly created page.

Any advice appreciated here thanks

Comment: Don't use relative paths for includes

Comment: how should i link to them, direct links?

Comment: @StuartWickenden use absolute, or real path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative paths in PHP are *not* relative to the physical file where the code is. Instead, they are relative to the working directory which, by default, is the directory of the main script, although you can even [change it on runtime](https://www.php.net/chdir):

> `bool chdir ( string $directory )`
> Changes PHP's current directory to `directory`

If you need paths that are relative to current *file*, you have to build an absolute path yourself:

```
include(__DIR__ . '/foo.php');
```

Comment: i solved with this 
`include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/home/functions.php");`
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Say if you have a folder called `myfunctions` you can use real path like this:

```
define('FUNCTION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/myfunctions'));
```

Then you would use that constant path like this:

```
include FUNCTION_PATH."functions.php";
```

Comment: is this acceptable? 
`include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/home/functions.php");`

Comment: @StuartWickenden no don't use `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` it wont work always